# How to find out if a table is still being updated in BigQuery?

Tags: python, firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics-firebase

I wrote a process that extracts the event data from BigQuery in JSON files and inserts them in Azure (to be used by Snowflake). Every 10 min the process is looking for new data in the **events_intraday_yyyymmdd** table and also checks for a new **events_yyyymmdd** table then extracts that. When doing a gap analysis later on I find that I have about 5% gap (more data in BQ than SN) and I think it is because at the time I am extracting the data from the daily table, it is still being updated. Is there a way to find out if the table is being used for INSERT, BULK INSERT, UPDATE processes so I can skip if so?

This is the code I am currently using to extract data

```
    # Check if new daily table exists
    print(f"Checking if new daily table exists")
    logging.info(f"Checking if new daily table exists")
    sql = f'''\
    begin
        create table if not exists `{tempDatasetName}` (id string, insert_date timestamp);
    
        create table if not exists `{dailyLogDatasetName}` (table_name string, insert_date timestamp);

        select distinct
            table_name
        from
            `{informationSchemaTables}`
        where
            regexp_contains(table_name, '^events_\\\\d{{8}}$')
            and table_name not in (select table_name from `{dailyLogDatasetName}`)
        order by 1;
    end
    '''
    query_job = bqClient.query(sql)
    query_job.result(timeout=7200)
    for job in bqClient.list_jobs(parent_job=query_job.job_id):
        if job.statement_type == "SELECT":
            results = list(job.result().to_arrow().to_pydict().values())[0]

    # Get missing rows from the daily table
    if results != []:
        for table in results:
            dailyDatasetName = f"{projectName}.{databaseName}.{table}"
            print(f"New Daily table {dailyDatasetName} found. Commencing extraction")
            logging.info(f"New Daily table {dailyDatasetName} found. Commencing extraction")

            requested_session = types.ReadSession(
                table=f"projects/{projectName}/datasets/{databaseName}/tables/{table}",
                data_format=types.DataFormat.ARROW,
                read_options=types.ReadSession.TableReadOptions(selected_fields=[])
            )
            read_session = bqStorageClient.create_read_session(
                parent=f"projects/{projectName}", read_session=requested_session, max_stream_count=streamCount
            )
            streams = read_session.streams
            obtainedStreamCount = len(streams)
            print(f"Obtained Streams. Starting {obtainedStreamCount} threads")
            
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=obtainedStreamCount) as executor:
                results = [
                    executor.submit(
                        scroller,
                        bqStorageClient,
                        stream,
                        table,
                        partition,
                        lowerFormat,
                        storageContainerName
                    ) for stream, partition in zip(streams, range(obtainedStreamCount))
                ]
                for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
                    f.result(timeout=None)
            try:
                streams.clear()
            except:
                pass

        # Insert into the dailylog table the table_name processed so it will skip it on the next run
        print(f"Inserting {table} into {dailyLogDatasetName}")
        logging.info(f"Inserting {table} into {dailyLogDatasetName}")
        sql = f'''\
        insert into {dailyLogDatasetName} values ('{table}', current_timestamp());
        '''
        query_job = bqClient.query(sql)
        query_job.result(timeout=7200)
```

Comment: I don't think that you can check if **events_intraday_** is being updated but if you can, it is probably by [getting its streaming metadata](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-streaming).

Comment: Note that the daily table is not derived from the intraday table and the data between them may differ. Take into account that: **1).** intraday export is a best effort exporting. **2).** BigQuery streaming export API cannot guarantee "exactly once" semantics, so a row might be exported multiple times in the intraday table. **3).** BigQuery streaming export may have failed RPCs (rarely but it may happen). And if there is any export failure, intraday export will not retry it, as it is essentially a streaming export with best effort.